# MUL operation in merged dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

data 1

```
import pandas as pd
#data 01
df_products = pd.DataFrame([{'Product ID' : 4109,'Price' : 5.0,'Product' : 'Sushi Roll'},
                   {'Product ID' : 1412,'Price' : 0.5,'Product' : 'Egg'},
                   {'Product ID' : 8931,'Price' : 1.5,'Product' : 'Bagel'}])
df_products = df_products.set_index('Product ID')
```

data2

```
df_invoices = pd.DataFrame([{'Customer' : 'Ali' , 'Product ID' : 4109 , 'Quantity' : 1},
                        {'Customer' : 'Eric' , 'Product ID' : 1412 , 'Quantity' : 12},
                        {'Customer' : 'Ande' , 'Product ID' : 8931 , 'Quantity' : 6},
                        {'Customer' : 'Sam' , 'Product ID' : 4109 , 'Quantity' : 2}])

df_invoices = df_invoices.set_index('Product ID')
```

merged data

```
df_overall = pd.merge(df_products , df_invoices , how='outer' , left_index = 
True ,right_index = True)
```

a new dataframe with total money paid

```
df_total = df_overall['Price'] * df_overall['Quantity']
```

**i want to show all the dataframes with the result!**

but this last line does not work right!

```
    df_result = pd.merge(df_overall , df_total , how='outer' ,
left_index = True , right_index = True)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, to define a new column in a dataframe use:

```
df_overall['Total'] = df_overall['Price'] * df_overall['Quantity']

print(df_overall)
```

Output:

```
            Price     Product Customer  Quantity  Total
Product ID                                             
1412          0.5         Egg     Eric        12    6.0
4109          5.0  Sushi Roll      Ali         1    5.0
4109          5.0  Sushi Roll      Sam         2   10.0
8931          1.5       Bagel     Ande         6    9.0
```

Comment: the sad thing is that i know how to add column but when i keep my mind on dataframes and data for so long i get confused.. thanks a lot for the help, much appreciated.

Comment: i see that you did  take the data science specialization from coursera.. i'm taking right now actually..i'm trying to make a career in data science then to machine learning..what is your opinion in that?..from a  professional point of view..i'm fresh graduate actually

Comment: I enjoyed the UoM Coursera Applied Data Science specialization.  It gave me a good foundation in python and data analysis.